# Select SUM then use it as the parameter for SELECT TOP

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I want these two SQL statements in one SQL command. Help :)

Statement #1:

```
SELECT SUM(nrofitems) as totItems 
FROM tblSets 
WHERE moduleexamID = 20
```

Statement #2:

```
SELECT TOP (cast(totItems as int)) questions
FROM tblQuestions 
WHERE moduleexamID = 20 
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: what do you mean by `ORDER BY NEWID()`, do you want to order it randomly ? The result of first query will always be **one** row, what do you mean by selecting `TOP` out of that? Arggh my brain is going to burst

Comment: Yes sir. I want need to sum the total number of items from table `tblSets` then I need to use the sum to select total number of items of questions from `tblQuestions`.. something like that. And the selected questions should be in random order.

Comment: Can you provide the schema of `tblSets` and `tblQuestions` ?

Comment: `;WITH cnt AS(SELECT SUM(nrofitems) AS totItems
FROM tblSets
WHERE moduleexamID = 20)
SELECT TOP(cnt.totItems) questions
FROM tblQuestions
CROSS JOIN cnt
WHERE moduleexamID = 20
ORDER BY NEWID()`

I used CTE but it's not working.

Comment: it will always return one row so whats the use of TOP? i think you required to get sum of nrofitems on  some other fields rather than the same one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table #tblSets (
    moduleexamID int,
    moduleId int,
    nrofitems int
)
go
create table #tblQuestions (
    moduleexamID int,
    body varchar(1024)
)
go
insert into #tblQuestions values
    (20,'aaaaaa'),
    (20,'bbbbbb'),
    (20,'cccccc'),
    (20,'dddddd'),
    (21,'eeeeee'),
    (21,'ffffff'),
    (20,'gggggg')
go
insert into #tblSets values
    (20,1,1),
    (20,2,2),
    (21,1,1),
    (22,1,3)
go
select top (
    select sum(s.nrofitems)
    from #tblSets s
    where s.moduleexamID=20
) *, newid() as id
from #tblQuestions q
where q.moduleexamID=20
order by id
go
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT tblQuestions.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) as RN
FROM tblQuestions 
WHERE moduleexamID = 20 
) as T1
WHERE RN<=
        ISNULL(
        (SELECT SUM(nrofitems) as totItems 
                FROM tblSets 
                WHERE moduleexamID = 20
        ),0);
```

Comment: Since `RN<=NULL` will never be true, such a condition would return 0 rows. Whereas with your `ISNULL` wrapper, you'll force the comparison to be `RN<=0` - which will *also* never be true - so I'm not sure why you think it's necessary.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: You're right it's not necessary in this case but I think it's explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You may try following also:

```
;WITH a AS (
    SELECT moduleexamID, SUM(nrofitems) as totItems 
    FROM tblSets 
    GROUP BY moduleexamID
)
SELECT b.questions
FROM a
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP (cast(a.totItems as int)) questions
        FROM tblQuestions 
        WHERE moduleexamID = a.moduleexamID
        ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID())
    ) b
WHERE a.moduleexamID = 20
```